# Why does List.Accordion get highlighted in white when being selected on IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm currently using the `List.Accordion` component by react native paper and when being selected on IOS the entire `List.Accordio`n component gets highlighted in white but on Android it instead gets highlighted with a dark shade and I'm not sure why. Could someone help?

Here is the current code for the component:

```
    <List.Accordion
        title='Advanced Options'
        titleStyle={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 19, fontWeight: 'bold' }} 
        onPress={() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
            }, 50);
        }}
        theme={{ colors: { text: 'white'} }}
        style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.theme, paddingHorizontal: 12 }}
    >
```

The `List.Accordion` component is currently styled with a dark blue background (making the white highlight quite obvious) and the `onPress` is in no way changing the style of the component, simply just scrolling the screen downwards to reveal the `List` items.

Answer (score 2):

you can use underlayColor props and set with transparent

```
<ListItem.Accordion
  underlayColor={'transparent'}
style{{overflow:'hidden',backgroundColor:'transparent',borderless:true}}containerStyle={{
```

overflow:'hidden',

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use text-decoration style property to customize it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).